# How to get the user input from the frame and save into txt file?

Tags: file, delphi, frame, firemonkey, tabcontrol

My programs run like this:

- I have a form with an add button, save button, and tabcontrol.
- When the add button in the form is clicked, the tabcontrol will add more tabitem. And the tabitem is basically added from myframe which includes users key-in value in a TEdit.

What I want to achieve is to print all the user input from the frame to a txt file when I click on the save `button(tick)` in the form. This is my code in form. Can anyone please give me some hint?

My frame Image:

[image]

My form Image:

[image]

My code:

[image]

Comment: Please, post code as text, not as image. It's really important for answerers that might want to copy some sections of your code to point out any mistake/suggestion.

Comment: I can see a classic beginner's mistake in your code. Let's say that you have five tabs in your tab control. When you do `for i := 0 to TabControl1.TabCount`, you therefore do `for i := 0 to  5`. So you consider, in order, `tab 0`, `tab 1`, `tab 2`, `tab 3`, `tab 4`, and ... `tab 5`?!

Comment: You haven't specified the desired file format. Also, what part are you struggling with? Creating a text file in general? Obtaining the values from the edits and combo boxes? Obtaining the controls from the current tab index? Because if you know all these things, you can complete the entire task.

Comment: In addition, the text in your Q suggests that you want to save a particular tab to a file, but your code screenshot suggests that you want to save them all, because you have this loop in it.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes Sir, im really a beginner. Please correct me as im really struggling learning delphi. Please please, guide me. And btw, sorry for the ambiguous, my question is when I clicked on the save button, yes, i want to save all the information of Tedit and Tcombobox from the frame and finally print the input value into a txt file. And the thing is i dont know how can i achieve this. Appreciate if you can guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should teach you all the ingredients you need.

Create a new application. I chose to make a VCL application, but I double-checked that all the steps are the same in Firemonkey (FMX).

Add a few edit boxes and combo boxes, like this:

[image: Screenshot of a form with two edit boxes ("First name" and "Last name"), a combo box ("Sex"), and a button ("Save").]

Name the controls `eFirstName`, `eLastName`, `cbSex`, and `btnSave`, respectively.

Then write the following `OnClick` handler for the button:

```
procedure TForm1.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  DataFile: TMemIniFile;
begin
  DataFile := TMemIniFile.Create(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'PersonalData.txt'));
  try
    DataFile.WriteString('General', 'FirstName', eFirstName.Text);
    DataFile.WriteString('General', 'LastName', eLastName.Text);
    if cbSex.ItemIndex <> -1 then
      DataFile.WriteString('General', 'Sex', cbSex.Items[cbSex.ItemIndex]);
    DataFile.UpdateFile;
  finally
    DataFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You need to add both `IniFiles` and `IOUtils` to your `uses` list (at least the `implementation` one).

Now, if you fill in the form,

[image: The same form now filled in.]

and click the `Save` button, the following file is created:

```
[General]
FirstName=Andreas
LastName=Rejbrand
Sex=Male
```

It isn't evident from the screenshots alone, but if you are at the top edit box and press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key repeatedly, you go to the second edit box, to the combo box, and then, finally, to the button. This is because I made sure that the *tab order* is correct. You should do the same.

Also notice the underlined characters. These are called *keyboard accelerators*. If I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, for instance, focus will move to the `First name` field. This is achieved by giving the label the caption (text) `&First name:` and assigning the corresponding edit control to the label's `FocusControl` property.

In this case, the button is `Default`, meaning that it is *the* button that responds to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. If it hadn't been default (and in your GUI, that might not make sense), I would have given it the caption `&Save` and changed `&Sex:` to `S&ex:`. Can you guess why?

## Other approaches

You can also use a `TStringList`:

```
procedure TForm1.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  DataFile: TStringList;
begin
  DataFile := TStringList.Create;
  try
    DataFile.AddPair('FirstName', eFirstName.Text);
    DataFile.AddPair('LastName', eLastName.Text);
    if cbSex.ItemIndex <> -1 then
      DataFile.AddPair('Sex', cbSex.Items[cbSex.ItemIndex]);
    DataFile.SaveToFile(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'PersonalData.txt'),
      TEncoding.UTF8);
  finally
    DataFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: BTW, I tried to make the same app in FMX, and discovered that (1) I get a beep sound on Alt+F etc., (2) I cannot select my sex by pressing `M` (or `F` or `O`) when the CB has focus, (3) I cannot navigate the CB in its dropped down state using the arrow keys, (4) in the dropped down state, the "list box" seems to demand a mouse hover effect, but there isn't any, and (5) in the dropped down state, the "list box" has an unnecessary scroll bar. This is why I am not a huge fan of FMX: you find roughly five bugs per minute.

Comment: Before that Sir, is TMemIniFile suitable for android application? And ya im building FMX.

Comment: And also, what if I want to save all this in TStringList, is that possible? because i dont know how can i convert all my Tedits and Tcombobox into TStringlist

Comment: @wlsiow96: I don't know. I know nothing about Android. But I would suspect so. Although the `TIniFile` uses the Windows API, the `TMemIniFile`is implemented entirely in Pascal. It's actually based on an ordinary `TStringList`. But just to be sure, I'll update my A with a `TStringList` based solution.

Comment: @wlsiow96: I am not sure I understood that comment. Do you mean that you want to save all tabs (users), not only a single tab (user)?

Comment: Yaya Sir, im sorry. I would ilke to save all the tabs and write to a txt file. Btw Sir, may I know the parameter of StrList.AddPair(const Name, const String), whats the correct value i should put into the parameters? For example, based on my diagram, say if i want to get the value of initial capital, what parameter i should write? because i cant understand what is the difference in the parameter

Comment: `AddPair('A', 'B')` will write the line `A=B` to the text file. So if you have a `TEdit` called `eFirstName`, then `AddPair('FirstName', eFirstName.Text)` will write the line `FirstName=Andreas Rejbrand` (if that's the text you entered in the edit box) to the text file. You need to chose what the "key" before the equals sign is for each field; that's part of the *specification of the file format*, which is designed by *you*.

Comment: If you want to save multiple tabs/users, you need first to decide if you want to save them all in one file, or if you want to create one file per tab/user. Then you only need to write a loop and take care of one tab/user at a time. How to access the controls from the main form's code depends on how the controls are placed on the frame and form, and that you didn't tell us in your Q.

Comment: But now I need to work on some other stuff for a while! :)

Comment: OK Sir, got it. But Sir, why is it when I declared:

strList.AddPair('InitialCapital', initialCapital_edit.Text);

It will shows (Undeclaired Identifier 'initialCapital_edit') ??

Comment: That's because `initialCapital_edit` isn't in scope. Probably it belongs to the frame and your code belongs to the main form -- two different files, even. If your frame class is `TMyFrame`, you could save all your created frames in an array `FMyFrames: TArray<TMyFrame>`. So every time you add a new tab/frame, add the frame instance (object) to this array. Then you can do `FMyFrames[TabControl1.TabIndex].initialCapital_edit` do access the `initialCapital_edit` of the `FMyFrames[TabControl1.TabIndex]` frame, that is, on tab index `TabControl1.TabIndex`.

Comment: It's important that you understand that the fact that tab 4 is visible on screen (for example) doesn't make the identifier `initialCapital_edit` refer to that tab's control. The source code basically has no idea which tab is currently active. You need to save references (pointers) to each frame manually, and access each frame's controls using these pointers.

Comment: Lol Sir, do u provide any delphi online class? I would really like to attend your class if you have.

Comment: @wlsiow96: Thanks, but unfortunately I don't give any classes! :) Keep up the good work learning Delphi!

Comment: Btw Sir, if i want to add as many tabs as i want, is array still suitable to be used in this case? Or should i store the tab item into TList? And im wondering even array or TList, it only stores the string right? So is it still possible to store the tabitem/frame into array or TList? Sorry Sir, i am a very weak beginner. Appreciate if you can share more

Comment: @wlsiow96: Using a `TList` is a great idea. Then you can simply use its `Add` method to add a new one. If you use an array, you first need to use `SetLength` to reallocate it with the new size, and then populate the new, last, item. And unnecessary heap (re)allocations are wasteful. In practice, this isn't an issue unless you create hundreds of thousands of tabs, though. But since the `TList` is so convenient, that's an excellent choice in this case.

Comment: In any case -- array or list -- the element's type should be your frame class. So each element is a pointer to the frame object. Using this pointer, you can access all controls, fields, properties, and methods of this particular frame. In your case, you'll be accessing the edits and combo boxes. (So no -- the elements are not strings.)

Comment: For example, if your frame class is `TMyFrame`, you'd use `TArray<TMyFrame>` or `TList<TMyFrame>`. You could also use `TObjectList<TMyFrame>` if you want the list to *own* the frames (=be responsible for freeing them).