# How a TList can get the input value from a Frame's TEdit/TCombobox

Tags: delphi, frame, firemonkey, tabcontrol, tlist

The Main form contains `TTabControl` which can create some tabs, dynamically. Whenever I add a new tab, a frame is created and add into the new tab. And finally, I will save all these `TTabItem` into a `TList`.

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  TabControl1: TTabControl;

procedure TForm1.AddNewTab;
var
  profileFrame :TProfileFrame;
begin
  profileFrame := TProfileFrame.Create(Self);

  //TabItem
  TabItem := TabControl1.Add();
  inc(tab_name_Count);
  tabItem.Text := tab_name_Count.ToString;
  //
  profileFrame.Parent := tabItem;
  tablist.Add(TabItem);
end;
```

And this is my frame:

```
TProfileFrame = class(TFrame)
 Name: TEdit;
 Gender: TComboBox;
```

Finally, how can I get the (Name) and (Gender) value in the frame, and print it out in main form? If let say i created 4 tabs, each tabs has its own frame, how can i get the value from different frame?? Im super confuse and new to Delphi.

Comment: You could pass a reference to your main frame into the dynamically created frames, or store the references to your newly created frames in your main frame (depending on which way you'd like to communication going).

Comment: "tabcontrol", "frame", "add button", "name", "gender"... Why do two different accounts seem to work on the same project? Related: [How to get the user input from the frame and save into txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63227215/4299358)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is your frames' variable are procedure local variable.

I see different ways to solve your problem.

First: using `TObjectList`:

```
uses ..., System.Generics.Collections;

TForm1 = class(TForm)
  TabControl1: TTabControl;
private
  FFrames:TObjectList<TProfileFrame>;    

procedure TForm1.AddNewTab;
var
  profileFrame :TProfileFrame;
begin
  //TabItem
  TabItem := TabControl1.Add();
  profileFrame := TProfileFrame.Create(TabItem); 
  inc(tab_name_Count);
  tabItem.Text := tab_name_Count.ToString;
  profileFrame.Parent := tabItem;
  if not assigned(FFrames) then
    FFrames := TObjectList<TProfileFrame>.Create(false); //we don't need ObjectList to own Frame, I suppose, so we have to pass `false` into Create method
  FFrames.Add(profileFrame);
  tablist.Add(TabItem);
end;

//Just to demonstrate how to get value from frame
function TForm1.GetGenderFromFrame(ATabItem:TTabItem):String;
var i:integer;
begin
  result := '';
  if FFrames.Count > 0 then
  for i := 0 to FFrames.Count - 1 do
    if FFrames[i].TabItem = ATabItem then
    result := FFrames[i].Gender.Selected.Text;
end;
```

Or you can use another way (checked on Delphi 10.1 FMX Project). You have to change your procedure like this:

```
procedure TForm1.AddNewTab;
var
  profileFrame :TProfileFrame;
begin  
  //TabItem
  TabItem := TabControl1.Add();
  profileFrame := TProfileFrame.Create(TabItem);
  inc(tab_name_Count);
  tabItem.Text := tab_name_Count.ToString;
  //
  profileFrame.Parent := tabItem;
  tablist.Add(TabItem);
end;
```

Now your frame has owner: `TabItem`. And `TabItem` has components. We can use it:

```
function TForm1.GetGenderFromFrame(ATabItem:TTabItem):String;
var i:integer;
begin
  result := '';
  if ATabItem.ComponentCount > 0 then
  for i := 0 to ATabItem.ComponentCount - 1 do
    if ATabItem.Components[i] is TProfileFrame then
    result := (ATabItem.Components[i] as TProfileFrame).Gender.Selected.Text;
end;
```

P.S. You can use `for ... in ... do` instead of `for ... to ... do`, it can be better, but it's up to you.